# "Starting version 219" after kernel upgrade to 3.19.0-18

Tags: kernel, lightdm, 15.04, fglrx

Today after kernel upgrade from 3.19.0-**16** to 3.19.0-**18** lightdm fails to start.

GPU driver is fglrx installed from "Additional drivers" tab of "Software & updates".

Try to enable service by running

```
sudo systemctl enable lightdm.service -f
```

doesn't help because service failed to start. See syslog:

```
May 22 19:49:05 SSERG-U38DT systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
May 22 19:49:05 SSERG-U38DT systemd[1]: Startup finished in 1.910s (kernel) + 2.987s (userspace) = 12.728s.
May 22 19:49:07 SSERG-U38DT systemd[1]: lightdm.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 22 19:49:07 SSERG-U38DT systemd[1]: Unit lightdm.service entered failed state.
May 22 19:49:07 SSERG-U38DT systemd[1]: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies of lightdm.service.
May 22 19:49:07 SSERG-U38DT systemd[1]: lightdm.service failed.
May 22 19:49:07 SSERG-U38DT systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
May 22 19:49:07 SSERG-U38DT systemd[1]: Stopping Graphical Interface.
May 22 19:49:07 SSERG-U38DT systemd[1]: Starting Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen...
May 22 19:49:07 SSERG-U38DT systemd[1]: Started Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen.
May 22 19:49:07 SSERG-U38DT systemd[1]: Started X.org diagnosis failsafe.
May 22 19:49:07 SSERG-U38DT systemd[1]: Starting X.org diagnosis failsafe...
May 22 19:49:07 SSERG-U38DT systemd[1]: Reached target Graphical failsafe fallback.
May 22 19:49:07 SSERG-U38DT systemd[1]: Starting Graphical failsafe fallback.
```

Choosing grub boot option of previous 3.19.0-16 kernel - system boots normally.

How to fix, please?

Comment: I think a best way is to lock your kernel version to 3.19.0-16 for a while and report the bug to launchpad.

Comment: @karel - sorry, my issue is slightly but different. The solution from #603398 doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today after next set of kernel updates the issue has gone.
Now Ubuntu 15.04 boots normally.

```
sserg@SSERG-U38DT:~$ inxi -F
System:    Host: SSERG-U38DT Kernel: 3.19.0-18-generic x86_64 (64 bit)
           Desktop: Unity 7.3.2  Distro: Ubuntu 15.04 vivid
```

Comment: But I do not see any changes in the kernels. There was only one 3.19.0-18. You probably interrupted upgrade and linux-image-extra did not install or something of that kind.

Comment: @Pilot6 - I agree that issue gone by unclear reasons. But yesterday no updates left more and reboot been requested. Today I got the update notification again and made updates.

Is there any way to check and compare both updates logs to find something?

Comment: You can look in /var/log/apt/history.log

Comment: `Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.19.0-18-generic cannot be found.`

Comment: Headers did not install and fglrx could not build for a new kernel.

Comment: Thx @Pilot6 - I have typed the same.
Examining /var/log/apt/term.log gave me the following line for **yesterday** 
`Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.19.0-18-generic cannot be found.`
Because of that fglrx and lightdm became misconfigired 
Today's update fixed this. 

Note: I have fresh installation of 15.04 and switched to proprietary fglrx by conventional Ubuntu way so kernel headers should be installed because gpu driver depends on it.